# not isnull or empty in sql statement does not block nulls

Tags: sql-server

simple question.

```
where not isnull([AddStreet], '') = ''
```

This seems to be failing, and I still get nulls and empties.
How do I prevent nulls AND empties from going forward?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that this is part of a larger query and somewhere you're using an "unguarded" `or` that renders this part of the `where` clause entirely optional. Not that we can say for sure given the lack of a complete example.

Comment: `WHERE AddStreet <> ''` is sufficient. That doesn't evaluate to true for either null or empty string. But as @Damien says there must be something else going on that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE ISNULL([AddStreet], '') != '';
```

or even just

```
WHERE AddStreet != '';
```

Comment: no.  I tried `<>` and NOT, I couldn't get it.  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 it's also possible with NOT. WHERE NOT (ISNULL([AddStreet], '') = ''), but my version is more common for SQL.